# Como funciona este codigo recursivo?

Tags: javascript, recursión

```js
function recur(n, cur) {
          if (!cur) {
            cur = 0;
          }
          if (n < 2) {
            throw new Error("Error");
          } 
          if (n === 2) {
            return 1 / n + cur;
          }
          console.log(n-1);
          console.log(cur + 1 / (n * (n-1)));
          return recur(n - 1, cur + 1 / (n * (n-1)));
    }
    
    const result = recur(5, 5);
    console.log(result);
```

estoy viendo el codigo pero no entiendo como de resultado final me da 5.8 con esos parametros, mi analisis es que si no se cumples las tres condiciones de arriba, estos:

```
    if (!cur) {
        cur = 0;
    }
    if (n < 2) {
        throw new Error("Error");
    } 
    if (n === 2) {
        return 1 / n + cur;
    }
```

al no cumplirse ninguno de ellos, se vuelve a llamar a si mismo, pasandose los mismos parametros despues de resolver dicha operacion, es decir:

```
      return recur(5 - 1, 5 + 1 / (5 * (5-1))); //primera vez

      return recur(4 - 1, 0.3 + 1 / (4 * (4-1))); // segunda vez
```

y asi sucesivamente hasta que n sea igual a 2, pero haciendolo con esos parametros a mi me da al final 0.68888, y no da 5.8

Comment: Ahi te agregue un par de console.log para que veas como va haciendo la funcion. si queres sacalos....

Comment: pero en el segundo console, como da 5.05? no deberia de dar 0.3?

Comment: Como estas haciendo la cuenta? estaras mirando mal la precedencia de operadores? mira esto: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#precedencia_de_los_operadores

Comment: Es curioso porque `if (!cur)` siempre será verdadero si `cur = undefined`, `cur = null` o `cur = 0`. Básicamente, una if que a primera vista no hace nada importante.

Comment: fijate que cuando el valor de n es 2, es cuando realmente termina la funcion. Si 1/n+cur, se calcula primero 1/n (n es 2, entonces eso da 0.5) y luego sumas cur (que vale 5.3) y eso es lo que devuelve esta funcion recursiva...

Comment: @gbianchi si, estaba haciendo mal la operacion ajjaa, si da 5.05 y asi sucesivamente

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Acerca de la *recursividad*

Tu razonamiento es correcto salvo por un error, cada vez que se llama a la función recursivamente, el segundo parámetro es `cur = cur + (1/(n*(n-1)))`. Vos decís que debería ser (en la primera iteración) 0.3, pero es `5 + 1/5*(5-1)`, esto te da 5.05. Ahora el nuevo valor para cur es 5.05, y así sucesivamente hasta que `n = 2`. Te pongo una tabla con las iteraciones:

| Iteraciones | valor de n | valor de cur |
| --- | --- | --- |
| primera | 5 | 5 |
| segunda | 4 | `5 + 1/(5*4) = 5.05` |
| tercera | 3 | `5.05 + 1/(4*3) = 5.13` |
| cuarta | 2 | `5.13 + 1/(3*2) = 5.3` |
| última | 2 | `Retorno = 1/2 + 5.3 = 5.8` |

Cotejalo con las funciones de retorno y vas a entender.

---

### Acerca de la *precedencia de los operadores*

Aparentemente el error de @plus es con la precedencia de los operadores y no por no comprender la recurrencia del código.

La precedencia de los operadores en una expresión nos indica ***qué se evalúa primero***. Es decir, *cuáles operandos y con qué operador* resuelvo primero. Por ejemplo:

- `1 + 2*3 = 7 y no 9`
- `(1+2) * 3 = 9 y no 7`
- `2 * 5^3 = 250 y no 1000`
- `5*3 - 4/2 + 3 = 16`

**Nota:** Dejé en torno de algunos operadores un espacio y en otros no, para ejemplificar más graficamente la prioridad en las operaciones.

Cada lenguaje tiene sus propios operadores y su propia regla de precedencia. En general existe cierta coincidencia en cómo evalúa la precedencia cada lenguaje, especialemente en los operadores matemáticos básicos como son `+ - * / ()` y los lógicos `and, not y or` y relacionales `== < > !=`, etc.

Si queremos alterar la precedencia natural de los operadores, debemos usar paréntesis encerrando la expresión que deseamos se evalúe primero, ya que tienen la precedencia superior. Siempre se evalúa de izquierda a derecha una expresión. Para la precedencia de los operadores matemáticos, es bueno recordar el acrónimo **PEMDSR**, que quiere decir:

1. **P** -> *Paréntesis*
2. **E** -> *Exponenciación*
3. **M** -> *Multiplicación*
4. **D** -> *División*
5. **S** -> *Suma*
6. **R** -> *Resta*

Es decir, primero se evalúan todas las expresiones dentro de paréntesis, luego todas las potencias, multiplicaciones y así hasta por último, la resta.
En todo caso, si tenemos dudas, siempre es bueno *condicionar* la precedencia usando paréntesis para así asegurarnos que allí no tenemos un error. También es buena idea comprobar con una *calculadora científica*. Aunque es mejor idea aprenderlo de forma definitiva ;-)

Hasta aquí, en línea general, para la mayoría de los lenguajes. Específicamente para JavaScript, [aquí hay una tabla de precedencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#precedencia_de_los_operadores) que se puede consultar.

Bueno, espero que te sirva. ¡Saludos!

Comment: bellisimo, gracias amigo

Comment: Agregalo una explicacion sobre precedencia de operadores (que es el problema) y es hermoso

Comment: Perdón por pedirte esto @gbianchi, pero me podrías explicar bien a lo que te referís (con gusto lo hago). Soy totalmente nuevo (empecé esa mañana), tampoco soy programador profesional (sé lo que es la precedencia de operadores), pero aunque soy medio jovato, quisiera serlo. Gracias.

Comment: Mas alla de la recursividad, el problema de OP fue hacer mal las cuentas... lee al respecto aca... https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#precedencia_de_los_operadores... es importante el orden de los operadores al hacer las ecuaciones...

Comment: Perfecto, te había entendido cualquiera. Ni bien pueda hago el anexo de precedencia. Gracias por la sugerencia.

Answer (score 2):

Según algunas pruebas y debuggear el código llegué a la siguiente conclusión:

El resultado final en todos los casos probados (para todo n entero positivo) en la funcion `recur(n, cur)`, es `cur + (n - 1) / n`.

Explicación del funcionamiento:

El primer `if` comprueba si **cur** es **0**, **null** o **undefined** y de ser así lo define en 0. Deduzco que hace esto por si quieres usar la función sin pasar el parámetro **cur**. De no hacerlo, éste será **undefined** y si operáramos con él recibiríamos un **NaN**.

```
if (!cur) {
    cur = 0;
}
```

El segundo `if`, en vista de la conclusión a la que llegamos (`cur + (n - 1) / n`) devuelve un error, ya que su funcionamiento no está pensado para valores de `n` menores a 2.

El tercer `if` es la última comprobación. Como solo hay un caso en el que n sea 2 igual a 2, podríamos reemplazarlo por:

```
if (n === 2) {
    return 1 / 2 + cur;
}
```

Finalmente llega el lugar dónde la magia ocurre. Entendamos la expresión `recur(n - 1, cur + 1 / (n * (n-1)))`:

Aquí lo que se hace la función es llamarse a sí misma.

`n - 1` es el anterior de **n**. Si **n** es 5, la próxima llamada será con `n = 4`. Y está bien que sea así ya que en este caso, si **n** permaneciera constante o aumentara, entraríamos en un bucle infinito. Deducimos entonces que **n** se encarga de llevar la cuenta y permitir que la recursión llegue a su fin.

El parámetro que lo recibe no es nada más y nada menos que **cur**. Visto esto nos damos cuenta que **cur** es el parámetro usado para llevar la información.

En cuanto a `cur + 1 / (n * (n-1))`, lo que hace es sumarle a nuestra variable **cur**, el inverso del producto de `n` por su anterior.

Para concluir, iba a hacer un análisis como el hecho por **Juan Pablo** pero me ganó. ¿Para qué repetir lo que alguien ya hizo?

Comment: brutal la respuesta, muchas gracias por tu tiempo amigo ajajjaa